# How to use ${LSB_JOB_INDEX} to run a for loop in LSF platform

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, hpc, lsf

I have a for loop that looks like this, and I want to convert it to an array job.
I want to run 100 jobs in parallel, but I am not entirely sure where I can add
the `${LSB_JOB_INDEX}` parameter.

Any help or guidance is welcome!

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J My_array[1-100]      #job name AND job array
#BSUB -n 3               #number of cores
#BSUB -R span[ptile=1]
#BSUB -W 00:10            #walltime limit: hh:mm
###BSUB -q queuename      #specify queue is optional
#BSUB -o Output_%J_%I.out #output - %J is the job-id %I is the job-array index
#BSUB -e Error_%J_%I.err  #error - %J is the job-id %I is the job-array index 

path=./home/

for each in *.bam 
do 
samtools coverage ${each} -o ${each}_coverage.txt
done
```

Thank you for your time; any help is appreciated. I am a starter at `LSF` and quite confused

Answer (score 1):

You may need to rename your `*.bam` files to contain the job array index number (or have another way of mapping the index number to the input filename). For example, if your input files are called `data_1.bam`, `data_2.bam`, ..., `data_100.bam`, then you can modify your LSF script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J My_array[1-100]      #job name AND job array
#BSUB -n 3               #number of cores
#BSUB -R span[ptile=1]
#BSUB -W 00:10            #walltime limit: hh:mm
###BSUB -q queuename      #specify queue is optional
#BSUB -o Output_%J_%I.out #output - %J is the job-id %I is the job-array index
#BSUB -e Error_%J_%I.err  #error - %J is the job-id %I is the job-array index 

path=./home/

samtools coverage data_${LSB_JOBINDEX}.bam -o data_${LSB_JOBINDEX}_coverage.txt
```

This should make each job in the array operate on a different input fiel specified by the `${LSB_JOBINDEX}` ID.