# LSF bsub add job ID to job string

Tags: jobs, lsf

While submitting an LSF job using `bsub`, I want to add the job ID to the job string.

> `bsub "mkdir job%J" -o %J.log`

If the jobID is `3456`, I was expecting to make a directory with name `job3456` but instead it is `job%J`. The log file, specified by `-o` has the name `job3456.log` which works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74003892/12715826), use `${LSB_JOBID}` and `${LSB_JOBINDEX}` for array.

Also, to prevent the shell from interpreting `${}` as a shell command, use the escape character `\`. The final solution to your problem is:

```
bsub "mkdir job%\${LSB_JOBID}" -o %J.log
```